# How can I split a string by newline in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a field in my `settings.html` where I am expecting the user to input multiple paragraphs separated by two newline characters. I would like to split this string of input into an array of strings, each representing a paragraph.

I would like to do something like this:

```
{% assign paragraphs = settings.intro | split: '\n' %}
{% for paragraph in paragraphs %}
    <p>
        {{ paragraph }}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to refer to the newline character in Liquid. How can I go about doing this? Is there some kind of work around?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% assign paragraphs = settings.intro | newline_to_br | split: '<br />' %}
{% for paragraph in paragraphs %}<p>{{ paragraph }}</p>{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Suggestion: add `strip_newlines` after `newline_to_br`.

Comment: Why not just `split` by `\n` like this: `settings.intro | split: '\n'` ?

Comment: @Nyasro See answer of morganbaz : "Liquid does not convert escape sequences into special characters." But otherwise it works (see his answer).

Answer (score 5):

If you do, in fact, need Shopify to split by newlines for any reason where you don't iterate with a for loop afterwards, it is indeed possible:

```
{% assign paragraphs = settings.intro | split: '
' %}
{% for paragraph in paragraphs %}
    <p>
        {{ paragraph }}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

ie. you need to type an explicit newline into your source code.

This is due to the way Liquid works, quoting from the documentation about [Types](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/types/):

> Liquid does not convert escape sequences into special characters.

Comment: OMG how crazy is that. It works, thanks a lot for the hint and great that you found out!

Answer (score 4):

@josh-browns answer got me pretty much there and might be enough for most instances.  However, I had some blank paragraphs coming through from user generated double lines.

Denilson Sá Maia comment of strip_newlines did not help with my markdown processor so I checked if each line was empty manually before outputting the paragraph.

```
{% for paragraph in paragraphs %}
    {% assign paragraph-length = paragraph | number_of_words %}
    {% if paragraph-length > 0 %}
        <p>{{ paragraph }}</p>
        IMAGE HERE
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This doesn't solve the blanks in the array, for that I iterated over the array to create a new one, with only valid content.  It would be really nice if there was a filter that worked on arrays, not just hashes.

```
{% assign all-paragraphs = content  | strip | newline_to_br | strip_newlines | split: "<br />"  %}
{% assign paragraphs = site.emptyArray  %}
{% for paragraph in all-paragraphs %}
    {% if paragraph and paragraph != "" and paragraph != site.emptyArray %}
         {% assign paragraphs = paragraphs | push: paragraph %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The filter tag uniq will strip all but one empty row too.

Comment: `newline_to_br` seems to apply only to a field which is a `textarea`. any way to apply this to a `richtext` component?

Comment: I believe richtext settings already use `<br>` instead of new lines